# access array from arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following arraylist

```
ArrayList<AnotherClass> exmapleName = new ArrayList<AnotherClass>();
// AnotherClass is a class I created, I store objects of the class in this array, the code to this doesn't matter this works.
```

Inside of exampleName I have different types of data

```
public AnotherClass (String someString,  int someInt, int anotherInt, int[] intArray, ArrayList<Integer> arrayList)
//Header of the constructor
```

Now what I need to do is access and store arrayList[0]. But I need to do it once the object has been created so there is actually something inside arrayList.

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to work

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass obj = new TestClass();
    obj.read(); //reads file
    testMethod();
```

}

```
       public void testMethod(){
         AnotherClass test1 = exampleName.get(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> test2 = test1.arrayList;
        int test3 = test2.arrayList[0];
```

}
    // I broke it down into separate lines to make it more understandable

compiler errors are as follows

```
cannot find symbol
                    int test3 = test2.arrayList[0];
symbol:   variable arrayList
location: variable test2 of type ArrayList<Integer>
```

1 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int test3 = test2.arrayList[0];
```

to

```
int test3 = test2.get(0);
```

You use brackets to access arrays' elements, & the `.get` method of an `ArrayList` to access its elements.

Comment: Much appreciated it worked, I was so close but so far

Comment: @ Sparta - You use brackets to access arrays' elements, & the .get method of an ArrayList to access its elements. ----- I thought because I'm trying to access a normal array though you use [ ] why do you have to use get?

Comment: Well, `test2` is an `ArrayList` of `Integer`s; so there is no such thing as `test2.arrayList`. Also, you can't do `test2[0]`.

Comment: ah of course I made a silly mistake, I confused myself with another class of mine thanks for the help